# WebDriver: PhantomJSDriver and save file dialog

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, webdriver, phantomjs

Investigating PhantomJSDriver for c#. I've found an issue: when I am trying to click an element which invokes file save dialog - PhantomJSDriver throws an exception:

> Error Message => 'Click succeeded but Load Failed. Status: 'fail''
>
> caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json,
>   image/png","Connection":"Close","Content-Length":"0","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:34660"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"","url":"/click","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"click","directory":"/","path":"/click","relative":"/click","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/click","queryKey":{},"chunks":["click"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/8839b140-08d7-11e3-9482-fda3a2d41a6f/element/%3Awdc%3A1376920756991/click"}

Is there any option how PhantomJSDriver can handle files save?

C# Code:

> var dr = new PhantomJSDriver();
>
> dr.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.mywebapps.com/Default.aspx");
>
> var link = dr.FindElementByXPath("//a[@href='Setup.exe']");
>
> link.Click();

Comment: updated with source code

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS reports that the click failed because it is checking to see if the content of page is valid.  In this case, since you're clicking a link to a .exe to download, it reports back that the click failed.

If you want to download a file, instead of clicking the link, using a `WebClient` to download it directly from a URL.

```
using (WebClient webClient= new WebClient())
{
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://yoururl/Setup.exe", "c:/temp/setup.exe");
}
```

You should read this blog post [How to Download Files With Selenium And Why You Shouldn't](http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/), which  if it doesn't talk you out of it, it does provide some very nice code samples on how to accomplish the file downloads.

Comment: Thank you, but this code was like a dummy. Let's imagine scenario where file download process was started by javascript and we don't have a direct access to file on webserver which means that we cannot use WebClient to download it. What should we do in this case?